# angular-ui/ui-tinymce setup method in tinymceOptions breaks model binding

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

I want to add a custom button to the tinymce toolbar, and added a setup function to tinymceOptions as discribed in the docs:

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
     setup: function (editor) {
               editor.addButton('myMethod', { //myCode }
     },
    //more options
}

<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="model.content"></textarea>
```

Adding the setup function breaks the binding with the model. Content added to the editor is not synched to the model and vice-versa.

Are there known issues with this approach? 
Angular version : 1.2.17 (Ionic framework) 
ui-tinymce version : 0.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old issue, but I answer it for future references.

This issue was already discussed and resolved in [angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/112](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/112). The solution is just to update the library.